# How do I convert month-year to a month word in MySql?

Tags: mysql, date, monthcalendar

I'm using MySql 5.5.37.  I have column of month-year numbesr, like the form

```
201601
```

How do I conver this to the month word followed by the year?  That is, the above would be converted to

```
January, 2016
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the function [date_format](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

example

```
select date_format('2016-01-01', '%M, %Y');
-- returns January, 2016
```

and it is necessary to convert `201601` to a datetime object, use the function [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). Note that `201601` will need a day-of-month component, which we can add by [concatenating](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) `01` to it to make it `20160101`

example

```
select str_to_date('20160101', '%Y%m%d');
-- returns 2016-01-01
```

combining the two,

```
select date_format(str_to_date(concat('201601', '01'), '%Y%m%d'), '%M, %Y')
-- returns January, 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `str_to_date()` for the first conversion and then use `date_format()` for the second conversion.  The format characters are `%Y` for a four-digit year, `%m` for a two-digit month, and `%M` for an month string (such as "January")

```
select 
  str_to_date('201601', '%Y%m')
  , date_format(str_to_date('201601', '%Y%m'), '%M, %Y')
```

The output would be

```
| 2016-01-00 | January, 2016 |
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically first use STR_TO_DATE() function by providing the pattern in your table and retrieve the data value and then format it by using DATE_FORMAT() function as you need.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE(field_name, '%Y%m'), '%M, %Y') 
FROM table_name
```

It doesn't matter if you field is string or numeric.